# IronPython every script in single ScriptScope

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ironpython

i have a small problem with my ScriptScope handling. Currently i have a lot of scripts in my database which where used in my application. I execute every script like this:

```
 myScriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(Code, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.File).Execute(myScriptScope);
```

No i have the problem, that if i import a namespace it one script, it is also imported in the other script. Now i had the idea, that i can use one ScriptScope for one script, but is this a good idea?
If i load every script(one script is one class) in it's own ScriptScope, are the classes global available? (Script A can use Script B and the other way round)

It is hard to find the information, when it is the best siutation to create a new ScriptScope.

Thank You!

Comment: Please check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046068/why-cant-i-change-variables-from-cached-modules-in-ironpython/21077137, don't miss the blog link.

Comment: You can create a scope with a shared part (e.g. imports) and private part visible to script which is currently running.

Comment: The scripts use each other?  Download scripts to directory and SetSearchPaths to include that directory.  Then just import the scripts.   The main script executing should do the importing.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I solved the problem by using only one scriptscope, because i want to access every thing every where. I've written my own implementation here: https://github.com/simplicbe/Simplic.Dlr you can take a look at the project and if you want, give some feedback. This shows some ways we use ironpython. Hope this helps. For more information, just ask :)